# Awk getline() function not working on empty lines

Tags: awk

Assuming I have a input file whose contents are

```
cat file


[source,I]

[source,more]

[source,1234]

[source,content]
```

Observe the two empty lines first followed by a pattern starting with `[source`, and then single empty line from subsequent point onwards. I want to remove *one or more* empty lines followed by a pattern ( or alternatively put, delete one ore more empty lines above a pattern starting with `[source`). I want an output as

```
[source,I]    
[source,more]    
[source,1234]    
[source,content]
```

I worked out an `Awk` logic as

```
awk '!NF{getline n; if ( match(n, /^\[source/) )  {print n}}' file
```

which worked perfectly except it skipped the pattern that was following the two empty lines and produced an output as

```
[source,more]
[source,1234]
[source,content]
```

I tried why the `getline()` call failed by printing the line NR on which the `Awk` should have done the `match()` and printed the line,

```
awk '!NF{getline n; if ( match(n, /^\[source/) )  {print n} else {print NR}}' file
2                # Why did this fail for NR==2? 
[source,more]
[source,1234]
[source,content]
```

Wondering why it failed for `NR==2` when the `getline()` should have returned `[source,I]` and printed the same after matching the regex.

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4-p1, GNU MP 6.1.1)
```

Comment: You can get the output you want from that input file with just `awk 'NF' file`. If that's not all you're trying to do then update the question so the input better represents your real problem.

Comment: @EdMorton: Updating it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see what's happening if you add debugging prints up front:

```
$ awk '{print ">", NR, NF, $0} !NF{getline n; if ( match(n, /^\[source/) )  {print n} else {print NR}}' file
> 1 0
2
> 3 1 [source,I]
> 4 0
[source,more]
> 6 0
[source,1234]
> 8 0
[source,content]
```

So awk reads the line 1 which is empty so `!NF` is true so it does a getline to read line 2 which is also empty to it doesn't match() and instead prints the current line number which is 2.

Now awk reads line 3, `[source,I]`, which is non-empty so `!NF` is false so the action block is not executed and that 3rd line is simply discarded.

Now awk reads line 4.... and so on.

Of course getline is the wrong approach for a problem like this anyway and once you modify your sample input/output we can show you for sure how to do what you want the right way but it SOUNDS like this is what you're really trying to do:

```
$ awk 'NF{if (/^\[source/) print buf $0; buf=""; next} {buf = buf $0 ORS}' file


[source,I]

[source,more]

[source,1234]

[source,content]
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, Missed the part with `getline()` function (really trivial) after line 1 and with one get line call, line 3 is parsed! was wrongly assuming it will be parsing line 2 and read line 3 as the next get line result. (Hope I made sense with the comment)

Comment: Yeah use of `getline` is tricky stuff, that's why I wrote http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline and included the couple of situations where you SHOULD use it.

Comment: Also it is more of a `X-Y` problem, just trying to understand why `getline()` wasn't working, makes sense now though. Can't really think of a more proper input for this case.

Comment: @Inian: I think I tried to explain the same thing in above solution and comment, not sure if I was not clear in it.

Comment: @Inian I'd just have added some non-blank lines that have blank lines before them but dont contain `[source` so a solution would have to handle not printing those and either buffering the blank lines before them or not, whichever is the desired behavior.

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes Ed! The `buf` logic makes more sense. bookmarked the answer now for future reference. Appreciate your time again!

Answer (score 2):

If `getline` is mandatory, You can try with `do ... while` in `gawk`

```
 awk '!NF{
     do getline n; while(length(n)==0); 
     if ( match(n, /^\[source/) ) print n}' file
```

you get,

```
[source,I]
[source,more]
[source,1234]
[source,content]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Agree it is getting me the desired output, but I want to understand why my attempt is not reading the next line when `NR==2`!

Comment: @Inian First iteration enters since first line obey the `!NF` condition, then reads n that is empty and this doesn't print, then the third line doesn't obey the `!NF` condition and doesn't enter in block code

Comment: Jose: My problem is simply put at `NR==2`, the `getline()` should have read the next line `[source,I]` and printed it right? I agree `NR==3` would failed the `!NF` condition which I am not doubting.

Comment: @Inian: I think I tried to explain in my edited version of explanation now. So when 1st line comes !NF is TRUE then it goes inside and getline comes into picture and puts cursor to 2nd line and save it to n. Now n is NULL so 2nd line number will be printed. Then When it comes out of !NF condition, awk has line 2 in it so it will move to line 3 now. Then it will not process line 2 again so line 2's !NF will never be executed again. Hence it is failing for line 2. Am I clear now sir ?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM.: It finally turned out to be a `X-Y` problem, I had a mis-conception about `getline()` call, which seemed pretty clear after seeing Ed Morton's answer. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

@Inian: Off course it will print second line number only because getline n means cursor goes to next line from 1st line and obviously when it goes to 2nd line then if you do print NR, it will print line 2 only.
So when cursor comes very first line it sees !NF and enters in it and then getline makes sure it should go to 2nd lines and stores it's value to n so 2nd line is empty too so it will print the number of line there.

Suggestion for code IMHO:

```
awk '!NF{getline n; if ( match(n, /^\[source/) )  {print n} else {print NR};next} NF'  Input_file
```

By doing a minor change into your code you will be able to get the 3rd source line too which was missing in you code. So here you are checking when NF is NULL which will work when 1 empty and next is source lines following will work even you have n number of empty lines and then source line. So adding NF in above and next in !NF condition should do the trick too.

You could remove printing NR in above if it is not required. I apologies if I miss something here, let me know if this is help.

EDIT: As Inian asked why it is failing on 2nd line, let me give a try if I understood problem correctly and could explain here.

```
awk '!NF                       ###### !NF, checking that if any line is empty or not, if it is empty then do following.
{getline n;                    ###### getline n, means go to next line(which will be 2nd line now) and have it's value into variable named n.
if ( match(n, /^\[source/) )   ###### if n matches the regex pattern then do following, NOTE as n is EMPTY in case of 2nd line is empty,
                                      so it will NOT pass the if condition it will go to else and print the line number which is 2.
{print n} else {print NR}}'    ###### printing n in case if condition is TRUE. using else if above condition is NOT true.
```

Comment: This is not answering my question! My problem is not why it is printing the second line number. Read it once again.

Comment: Sorry I missed it if you meant to explain the same, Ed Morton's answer was more clear, a `++` for your time.